# Symmetric group in terms of block permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, free-groups

For $i+j+k=N$, consider the permutation $\Pi_{i,j,k}\in S_N$, which keeps the numbers $0,\ldots,i-1$ fixed, and exchanges the numbers $i,\ldots,i+j-1$ with the numbers $i+j,\ldots,i+j+k-1$.

$$\Pi_{i,j,k}(x)=
\begin{cases}
x & \text{if}\quad 0\leq x<i\\
x+k&\text{if}\quad i\leq x<i+j\\
x-j&\text{if}\quad i+j\leq x<i+j+k
\end{cases}
$$

$i=0$ is allowed. Rather obviously, $\Pi_{i,j,k}$ for different $i,j,k$ generate the whole symmetric group $S_N$. Is there simple set of relations for those generators, such that $S_N$ is the free group over the $\Pi_{i,j,k}$ modulo those relations?

Comment: I'm talking about relations like $\Pi_{0,i,j+k+l}\Pi_{j,k,i+l}\Pi_{0,k+j+l,i}\Pi_{i+k,j,l}=\Pi_{i,j+k,l}$ (for all $i$, $j$, $k$, $l$).